# Why `bindkey` in `.zshrc` does not apply unless i source the editor?

Tags: shell, zsh

So i want to be able to `cargo run` with Ctrl + o.

I figured out that in `zsh` that is spelled something like this: `bindkey -s '^o' 'cargo run ^M'`.  I put this in my `.zshrc`, but when i start a shell this command does not exist, so i have to `source ~/.zshrc` from inside the open shell. Then it works.

Why not on start?

Comment: What does it mean, to _start a fresh editor_? What editor are you talking to? And what is an **open** shell?

Comment: @user1934428 i meant just _start a shell_, apologies. I am using zshell.

Comment: If you start a **_new_** **interactive** shell, `~/.zshrc` **is** sourced, unless the variable `ZDOTDIR` is set.  See _man zsh_. It's not clear to me where your problem exactly is.

Comment: There is perhaps some error in your zshrc file that doesn't trigger when it's read the second time, or maybe you put it in the wrong location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the problem appears to have been that i've been putting my command definitions before the following:

```
export ZSH=~/.oh-my-zsh
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

Put your code *after*.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar problem. It is very likely that other plugin settings in your .zshrc override the new key binding. You can try to backup your .zshrc and only keep the key binding to see if it works. If it works, then gradually add other settings back to see which one causes the problem. In my case, it is the zsh-vi-mode.

Comment: Do you put your defs before either of 
`export ZSH=~/.oh-my-zsh`
`source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`
??

Comment: I do not use oh-my-zsh. But I define the function after `source blablabla.zsh`.